# Why java lets me add a Box(Raw type) to a List<Box<? extends Item>>

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

This code works, and I dont understand how the list is able to add a raw type box, I thought type erasure will set the type to their indicated bounds.
note: Paper class doesn't extends Bakery class.

EDIT: Is my understanding correct? the compiler typecasts the raw box type so that it can be added to the list? does this works only at compile time? so if I tried to get the value at runtime it will throw an exception?

```
class Violator {

    public static List<Box<? extends Bakery>> defraud() {
        List<Box<? extends Bakery>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Paper paper = new Paper();
        Box box = new Box<>();
        box.put(paper);
        list.add(box);
        return list;
    }
}
class Box<T> {
    void put(T item) { /* implementation omitted */ }
    T get() { /* implementation omitted */ }
}
```

Comment: You can assign raw type to generic type. For instance having `List<String> names; List raw = new ArrayList();` you can assign `names = raw;`. My guess is: because before generic types ware introduced, code was written like `List getNames() { /*generates and returns list containing Strings with names*/ }`. This let programmers use it like `List<String> names = oldPojo.getNames();` (with *warning*) - note that `getNames()` returns *raw* `List`. Because of that you can also assign your `Box box` (raw) to `Box<? extends Bakery>` or `Box<Bakery>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code does generate an unchecked conversion warning, as to why its permitted, from [Angelika Langer's blog](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Why%20are%20raw%20types%20permitted?)

## Why are raw types permitted?

> To facilitate interfacing with
> non-generic (legacy) code. Raw types are permitted in the language
> predominantly to facilitate interfacing with non-generic (legacy)
> code.
>
> *If, for instance, you have a non-generic legacy method that takes a
> `List` as an argument, you can pass a parameterized type such as
> `List<String>` to that method.  Conversely, if you have a method that
> returns a `List` , you can assign the result to a reference variable of
> type `List<String>` , provided you know for some reason that the
> returned list really is a list of strings.*

Your answer lies in  ***Conversely, if you have a method that returns a `List` , you can assign the result to a reference variable of type `List<String>`***. In your case you might have a legacy method that returns a Box

```
 // Legacy code
 private Box getBox(){
     // returns a Box which satisfy the Box<? extends Bakery>
 }
```

even though the returned result might satisfy the constraint `Box<? extends Bakery>`, there is no way to be completely sure, so you are allowed to add that box to your list

Comment: Why not use Java syntax instead of 'List of string'?

Comment: <String> was not being displayed inside quoted text and I was too lazy to try backticks. Thank you for motivating me